# matlab optimoptions save residual in variable

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I'm using the optimoptions function and I want to save the residual after each iteration in a variable. Now if I choose to display the iterations in the first line of the following code, I could see them in console, but is there anyway to save them as a vector variable? I have tried to get the residual output in the second line but it gives me only the result of the last iteration. Thank you.

```
options = optimoptions(@lsqnonlin,'Algorithm','Levenberg-Marquardt','Display','iter','StepTolerance',1e-4);
[params,resnorm,residual_opt,exitflag,output,lambda,jacobian] = lsqnonlin(@minDistance,params0,[],[],options);
angles = params(1:3);
R = euler2mat(angles);
T = params(4:6);
end
```

here is the display of iterations. I just want to use the third colomn.

```
                                        First-Order                    Norm of 
 Iteration  Func-count    Residual       optimality      Lambda           step
     0           7      5.4943e+09        3.84e+10         0.01
     1          14     7.39183e+08        8.74e+09        0.001        6.32624
     2          21     4.56928e+07         1.1e+09       0.0001        2.59042
     3          28     2.41748e+06        1.21e+08        1e-05        2.61414
     4          35          135873        1.39e+07        1e-06        1.45824
     5          42         8031.22        1.65e+06        1e-07       0.743095
     6          49         487.971           2e+05        1e-08       0.372708
     7          56         30.0687        2.47e+04        1e-09       0.186396
     8          63         1.86599        3.07e+03        1e-10      0.0931815
     9          70        0.116209             382        1e-11      0.0465832
    10          77      0.00724993            47.7        1e-12      0.0232892
    11          84     0.000452687            5.96        1e-13       0.011644
    12          91     2.82764e-05           0.744        1e-14     0.00582186
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the residuals?

Comment: I'd plot them in a figure in my own plotting window.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the optimization toolbox available to test this but you should be able to get the residuals in each iteration by defining an  [output function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/output-function.html) that is called each iteration.

In your optimization options you add your function handle as `'OutputFctn', @myOutputFunction`. In the function you can access the residual value (among other things) and either plot the values or save them to file.

```
function stop = myOutputFunction(x,optimValues,state)

% Do not use the user defined function to determine when to stop
stop = false;

% The following should be the value you are looking for in the 
% current iteration.
currentResidual = optimValues.residual;

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get all residuals directly without modifying the code of the function.

However, if you want to plot the residuals for all iterations, you can do it by adding the option 'PlotFcn' with the value '@optimplotfval'. See [documentation, Optimization options](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) for more information. You can even make your own plotting function based on the existing one.

--Hint--

To build a custom plot, start from one of them, for example `optimplotfval`. You can paste the code in a new file and rename the function. Delete the non-useful command, such as modifying the title. Retrieve from `varargin` an extra parameter being the handle of the axes you want to use, and use it in all plot functions.

For using this custom plot, make a closure on your custom plot:

```
'PlotFcn', @(x,optimValues,state)mycustomplot(x,optimValues,state, hMyAxis)
```

Comment: yes I have seen this option, however could I plot it not in a seperate window but in my window with my other plots?

Comment: @jiayi Some hints added for that.